sending text file to GNU Radio using FSK
There was a problem when transmitting a text file using FSK, the access code does not pass on the receiving side, and if it does, the information does not pass CHECK CRC32. When we use ZMQ blocks and transmit to ourselves, everything works out - Figure 3, but when we use two HackRFs for transmission, we are unable to receive the file - Figure 4.I'm confused about the output from my filter and the output from the demodulator. The modulator seems to be unable to determine when a “0” arrives at it. Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?
Reception scheme, Figure 1.
Transmission scheme,Figure 2.





Hi! Can you actually enter an actual image description, i.e. what the image shows where you're being asked to enter an image description? Then I can also add the images to your post (please let me know.)

Hello! I corrected the description!

I can't tell what "TX", "RX" and "EXIT" would mean to a reader with a problems with their sight. A good name would probably be "screenshot of the flowgraph that does the reception. Visible: Block foo connected to block baz" or such. Still, with some text at all, I can inline the images :)

Good afternoon I changed the diagram and added more explanation to the topic
